# Removing unwanted dividers/separators from the toolbar in QGIS 3.20.0

Tags: qgis-3

After moving/combining icons on the toolbar I'm left with unneeded spacers/separators. How can I remove these (highlighted in red)?

[image: Unwanted spacer highlights in red]

Comment: Did you try to remove the empty toolbars with Menu View  / Toolbars?

Comment: @Babel I'm actually using the toolbars so I don't want to get rid of the tools themselves. I've relocated the icons to a different row, but the separators remain.

Comment: You can read about the [interface customization](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#customization), specially about the `Switch to catching widgets in main application` tool. Using that tool, select the toolbars you want to hide from QGIS. You need to restart QGIS to see the results.